# Way to notify git when file is moved by dragging in Finder?

Tags: git, finder

I am using git to manage my dissertation, and have lots of pdf journal articles that I am slowly reorganizing with Finder as my directory structure normalizes over the next few months. I would love to find a way to tell git that these files have simply moved and not deleted and added as new files to avoid repo bloat.

Doing this from the command line is cumbersome when I have to move 20 of 30 files in a folder or folders.

Anyone have a nice way to do this? Or does git do it automatically and I just can't tell?

Thanks!

Comment: if you're using the word *"repo bloat"* and *"git"* at the same time .... well .... you're doing it wrong. Repositories like that are DESIGNED to track massive amounts of changes and files - there is no such thing like *"bloated"*, even leviathans like linux are handled pretty damn well. Also : this community is all about **programming** whereas your question is pretty much exactly system administration

Comment: @specializt - No such thing as a bloated repo?  Wrong.  The entire LFS project exists because of the wrongness of that claim.  As I note in my answer, this particular concern about bloat is misguided; but on the other hand, a repo of large binary files (like PDF) is exactly the type of repo that very well could suffer bloat.

Comment: what is *"suffer"* even supposed to mean? Performance issues? These should be reported via the GIT bugtracker, certainly not stack overflow - its a serious bug and should be addressed because repositories are not supposed to *"suffer"* just because someone pushed a large quantity of binary files and unless the user tries to clone the entire **history** of the repo with a single request the performance should be ... acceptable, at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what you "tell" git, or how you tell it, git will *always* understand a moved file as "file at this location deleted; file at this other location created".  It sometimes reinterprets this as "file moved from this location to this other location" in its output, but no special prompting is needed for it to do this.  But fundamentally there is no such thing as a "move" operation in git.

You mention your concern is repo bloat.  No need to worry.  Even if git sees two files with identical content, it only stores the content once.  The content is stored in an object called a `BLOB`.  The filename is stored in a "directory listing"-like object called a `TREE`.  So when you move a file, a new entry in a `TREE` (possibly in a different `TREE` object, if you've moved the file to a different directory) is simply made to point to the already-existing `BLOB`.

All of this is automatic.  You do of course have to add/commit the changes, but from there it's taken care of.

Comment: So it must use a checksum or something to see if it had the file somewhere previously?

Comment: Yes. At its core git is a "content-addressable file system" - a database of "objects" (such as the `BLOB` objects that represent file content) indexed by SHA1 checksum.  In an unpacked repo you can see how this works by examining `.git/objects`.  An object with SHA checksum `1234567890abcdeabcde1234567890abcdeabcde1234567890abcdeabcde1234567890abcdeabcde` would be stored at `.../.git/objects/12/34567890abcdeabcde1234567890abcdeabcde1234567890abcdeabcde1234567890abcdeabcde`.  When the database is packed, it becomes a little harder to examine "by hand" but the principle is the same.

Comment: Excellent. Smart design, if fast, which it obviously is. BST probably cranks through that

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF files have not changed at the same time  you moved them, then they will have the same hash value for their contents (even if you renamed the file as well as moved it to another directory.

Git will generally figure out on its own that this is a move/rename, at commit time. That's because it hashes the new paths, finds that it already knows about files with the same hashes. Then it sees that those files were deleted, and it figures out you just did a move/rename.

Comment: It doesn't "figure this out" at commit time, because it doesn't care.  It may identify the pair of operations (DELETE + ADD) as a move when presenting a diff, merging, showing status, etc.